# Searching a vector in java

Tags: java

I have created a vector of struct/class. It contains class members firstName lastName and Age.

```
class Person
{
     String firstName;
     String lastName;
     int Age;
}

class Vote
{
     Vector<Person> vec;
     public Vote(){
         vec =  new Vector<Person>();
     }    
     public void addElem(Person p)
     {
         v.addElement(p);
     }

}
```

I am trying to search the vector by any one from the following:

```
firstName,lastName,age.
```

After searching, the result should be the entire vector elements at that index. I was trying to do it with `vec.firstName.contains()` but this does not work. Is there a way I can search through the vector?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the entire vector elements at that index". You should specify an example of the input/output.

Comment: try to override toString() of person to print the info you need

Comment: if I search for firstName and it is found in the vector then it should return firstName, lastname and age of the matched firstname

Answer (score 5):

The easiest thing to do is iterate through the elements of the vector and compare each in turn.

```
public Person searchByFirstName(Vote v, String firstName) {
  for (Person p : v.vec) {
    if (p.firstName.equals(firstName)) {
      return p;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

You could do the same for each type of thing you want to search by. Obviously this example is an exact match; you could implement case insensitive matching or prefix matching by looking at the methods that the String class provides.

Comment: Don't you think p.firstName. should be p.getFirstName() ?

Comment: Not in his example - he hasn't shown any getters. In general, yes it's better to use getters than rely on public info. It's not clear from his code if he's lumping this all in one file or not.

Comment: If I have a file which contains firstName, lastName, Age written randomly and I am trying to search it in the vector. Will I have to write if loops and search linearly as shown above?

Answer (score 0):

create a `person` object and use:
 `vec.contains(personObj)` 
instead of
 `vec.firstName.contains()`